# display widget in a center of column

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my page I have a customized Appbar then I want to display a message with icon, and it should be in the center of the page. i mean the customized Appbar is on the top then in the center of the page we have the icon with the message

```
child: Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: [
          const CustomAppBar("Réglages et paramétrages", true, false,
              returnToHistory: true),
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment : MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: const [
                  Icon(Icons.warning, color: Color(0xFFFF9500), size: 100 ,),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: const [
                  Text(
                      "be careful",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,)

                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ]),
      )),
    ));
```

Comment: Your `CustomAppBar` should be at top? Can you include an image that are you trying to build

Comment: yes it must be on the top i did some changes on my question thank u !

Comment: It would be great if you could include an image,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try doing it this way by using an expanded widget to adjust the flex of the custom appbar and scrollview

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: const CustomAppBar("Réglages et paramétrages", true, false,
                  returnToHistory: true),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 7,
              child: Center(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: const [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.warning,
                        color: Color(0xFFFF9500),
                        size: 100,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "be careful",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove SingleChildScrollView and wrap the inner column with an expanded widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom appbar as widget and provide on `Scaffold`'s `appbar`. To do this, you need to `implements PreferredSizeWidget`

```dart
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;
  const CustomAppBar({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(title),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

And your layout will be

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const CustomAppBar(title: "Réglages et paramétrages"),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: const [
                      Icon(Icons.warning, color: Color(0xFFFF9500)),
                      Text(
                        "be careful ",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can find more about [ui/layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout) on flutter dev .

Comment: the customAppbar is a container widget that is why i put inside the body and not on the appbar

Comment: Yes, I do understand this. That's why I've `implements PreferredSizeWidget`. You can test the snippet then comment  if it works or not.